How to change the background opacity without making the characters transparent?
I want to change the background opacity of a node without making the characters more transparent.
    \documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\draw[ultra thick, blue,fill=red,] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[green,ultra thick,fill=brown] (1,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\node[black,fill=yellow] at (1,2){A};
\node[black,fill=yellow,opacity=0.3] at (1,-2){A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}



Replace
\node[black,fill=yellow,opacity=0.3] at (1,-2){A};

with
\node[black,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1] at (1,-2){A};

Complete mwe is:
\documentclass[border=0cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}   
\draw[ultra thick, blue,fill=red,] (0,0) circle (2cm);
\draw[green,ultra thick,fill=brown] (1,-2) rectangle (3,2);
\node[black,fill=yellow] at (1,2){A};
\node[black,fill=yellow,fill opacity=0.3, text opacity=1] at (1,-2){A};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}


